# 16 bit signed data format in PMBus spec

Tags: pmbus

The [PMBus specification](http://pmbus.org/Specifications/OlderSpecifications) (>= Rev1) specifies that the query command returns a data byte with a binary bit pattern of `001` in bits 4:2 if the format used for the queried command is a "16 bit signed number".

this is the only mention I can find of this data format (distinct from other 16 bit formats already covered by other bit patterns) within the PMBus standard.

What does this relate to? (AVS maybe?) Am I missing something silly?

<sub>*Note that I come at this from the device designer side rather than the host system side</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is just a 2's complement signed integer, as I believe.

Comment: Did you mean that this is a format made available for manufacturers to use as they wish? (I mean I know what a 16 bit unsigned integer consists of :D) But there are no specification defined commands mentioned that use it or any other mention of it in the spec *at all*

Comment: @Toby, no, I mean this just is the most widely used signed integer format. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.

Comment: Well this I know. I am asking *sepcifically* in the context of the PMBus specification however. All other formats used within this spec have information on *where* they are used, with which commands, etc. Conversely this format doesn't actually appear to be used! Thus my confusion in how it is included in the QUERY command.